# Trying to create 2 pie chart on 2 separate plot.js and it is not reflecting on index.html

Tags: javascript, html, charts, plotly

Two pie charts are created, but the 1st pie chart is not showing the data according to the dropdown. It always stays the same and the data is not updated. The second one works, however, fine. Here is my code:

```js
//first pie chart
function init() {
  var data = [{
    values: [0, 0, 5, 9],
    labels: ["Bass", "Chilean", "Fish", "Seafood"],
    type: "pie"
  }];

  var layout = {
    height: 600,
    width: 800
  };

  Plotly.plot("pie", data, layout);
}

function updatePlotly(newdata) {
  var PIE = document.getElementById("pie");
  Plotly.restyle(PIE, "values", [newdata]);
}

function getData(dataset) {
  var data = [];
  switch (dataset) {
    case "dataset1":
      data = [0, 0, 5, 9];
      break;
    case "dataset2":
      data = [0, 0, 5, 8];
      break;
    case "dataset3":
      data = [0, 0, 2, 1];
      break;
    default:
      data = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  }
  updatePlotly(data);
}

init();

//second pie chart
function init2() {
  var data2 = [{
    values: [1, 0, 42, 7],
    labels: ["Bass", "Chilean", "Fish", "Seafood"],
    type: "pie"
  }];

  var layout2 = {
    height: 600,
    width: 800
  };

  Plotly.plot("pie2", data2, layout2);
}

function updatePlotly(newdata2) {
  var PIE2 = document.getElementById("pie2");
  Plotly.restyle(PIE2, "values", [newdata2]);
}

function getData2(dataset2) {
  var data2 = [];
  switch (dataset2) {
    case "dataset4":
      data2 = [1, 0, 42, 7];
      break;
    case "dataset5":
      data2 = [0, 0, 1, 4];
      break;
    case "dataset6":
      data2 = [3, 7, 187, 37];
      break;
    default:
      data2 = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  }
  updatePlotly(data2);
}

init2();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<body>


  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Welcome </h1>
    <p>hypothesis: Seabass is a popular choice in non seafood setting restaurants among food reviewers</p>

  </div>

  <!-- first pie chart-->

  <h2>>Data collected among 300 Yelp reviews that words relating to seabass like seafood, fish, bass, chilean</h2>
  <h3>1) Search terms "Seabass" among 1000 restaurants in NYC sorted by most reviewed</h3>

  <select id="selDataset" onchange="getData(this.value)">
    <option value="dataset1">No.1 Joe's shanghai's @ 6158 reviews</option>
    <option value="dataset2">No.2 Eataly's @ 5499 reviews</option>
    <option value="dataset3">No.3 Ippudo's @ 3676 reviews</option>
  </select>
  <div id="pie"></div>
  <P>=============================================================================================================</P>

  <!-- Second pie chart-->

  <h3>2) Search terms "Seabass" among 1000 restaurants in NYC sorted by most recommended</h3>

  <select id="selDataset2" onchange="getData2(this.value)">
    <option value="dataset4">No.1 Fish cheek</option>
    <option value="dataset5">No.2 Au-zaatar-new-york</option>
    <option value="dataset6">No.3 Midtown catch</option>
  </select>

  <div id="pie2"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Both are shown. I have tried removing the second chart and the first one works. What may have gone wrong? I have indicated different variable names for each pie chart.

Image of not working chart:

[image: pic of not working pie chart]

Comment: thank you double-bee, I wanted to add more Javascript codes but the admin says the code is too long. I will edit the post and add in the libraries.

Comment: I tried using different methods like combing into 1 plot.js with 2 different set of data for the pie chart and it did not work. I might have to give up on having 2 pie charts on one html. I noticed that there is not many help resources or forums about creating 2 similar charts on 1 html page.

Comment: Why is the first chart (`dataset1`) not working? What would you like to happen? Which is the first pie chart and which the second one?

Comment: so I am creating 2 drop down on 2 separate pie charts. I have a JS files each pie chart function. the first chart does not work when i try to click the drop down options but 2nd pie chart works.

Comment: Hi double-beep, I entered the break but still having the same issues.

Comment: i tried too but the comments say its too long, I cant insert the full codes. is there any other way to post the full codes ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You've messed up with function names and you had defined `updatePlotly` twice. And you should simplify the code:

- Store in a variable (`pie_values`) the data you want.
- Don't define `init()`, `init2()`, `updatePlotly()` and `updatePlotly2()` - those are confusing. Instead, work with arguments.
- You should change some functions' and ids' name in order to make your code readable - i.e. use ids related to the content of the `<option>`/`<select>`, etc.

Here's what I'd suggest (I've removed some from the HTML to make it simpler - ignore those):

```js
const pie_values = {
  pie1: [{
    values: [0, 0, 5, 9],
    labels: ["Bass", "Chilean", "Fish", "Seafood"],
    type: "pie"
  }],
  pie2: [{
    values: [1, 0, 42, 7],
    labels: ["Bass", "Chilean", "Fish", "Seafood"],
    type: "pie"
  }],
};

function init(data, id) {
  var data = data;
  var layout = {
    height: 600,
    width: 800
  };

  Plotly.plot(id, data, layout);
}

function updatePlotly(newdata, id) {
  var PIE = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.restyle(PIE, "values", [newdata]);
}

function getData(dataset) {
  var data = [];
  switch (dataset) {
    case "dataset1":
      data = [0, 0, 5, 9];
      break;
    case "dataset2":
      data = [0, 0, 5, 8];
      break;
    case "dataset3":
      data = [0, 0, 2, 1];
      break;
    default:
      data = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  }
  updatePlotly(data, "pie");
}

function getData2(dataset2) {
  var data = [];
  switch (dataset2) {
    case "dataset4":
      data = [1, 0, 42, 7];
      break;
    case "dataset5":
      data = [0, 0, 1, 4];
      break;
    case "dataset6":
      data = [3, 7, 187, 37];
      break;
    default:
      data = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  }
  updatePlotly(data, "pie2");
}

init(pie_values.pie1, "pie"); // pie chart 1 init()
init(pie_values.pie2, "pie2"); // pie chart 2 init()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

  <!-- first pie chart-->

  <select id="selDataset" onchange="getData(this.value)">
    <option value="dataset1">No.1 Joe's shanghai's @ 6158 reviews</option>
    <option value="dataset2">No.2 Eataly's @ 5499 reviews</option>
    <option value="dataset3">No.3 Ippudo's @ 3676 reviews</option>
  </select>
  <div id="pie"></div>

  <hr/>
  <!-- Second pie chart-->

  <select id="selDataset2" onchange="getData2(this.value)">
    <option value="dataset4">No.1 Fish cheek</option>
    <option value="dataset5">No.2 Au-zaatar-new-york</option>
    <option value="dataset6">No.3 Midtown catch</option>
  </select>

  <div id="pie2"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much double-beep! It worked. The issue is with the function name. I am very new to this because I want to create an analysis on the flask-app web to show potential employers. This will help me a lot along the way. Thank you!